# Repository error with yum

Tags: package-management, yum, repository, connectivity

I cleaned `yum` (clean `metadata`, `packages`, `all`, etc...) and after that everytime I try to download or update or do something with `yum` I get the following error:

> http://"MY IP"/install/rocks-dist/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
>   [Errno 4] IOError:  Trying
>   other mirror. Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml)
>   for repository: Rocks-5.4. Please verify its path and try again

I tried removing every commented line (not pure comments) of all the repos I have in `yum.repos.d` but nothing happened.

This is what I get if I do `yum repolist`
[image]

Also found this in `yum.conf` (this is part of the file, should this be here? With my IP?

> [Rocks-5.4]
>
> name=Rocks 5.4
>
> baseurl=http://**"MYIP"**/install/rocks-dist/x86_64

**NEW:**

I removed the Rocks repository from my `yum.conf` and now I get this error with `yum update`:

> YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file. 
>   Eg. Invalid release/
>   http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/addons/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
>   [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found Trying other mirror. Error:
>   Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository:
>   addons. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: Can you add to your question your repository file, and anything related to `Rocks-5.4` ?

Comment: @ThomasGros Done, I dont know what you mean by anything related to Rocks

Comment: Do you have a repository hosted on your (or one) machine located at  your IP ? The problem seems to be related to your `Rocks-5.4` repository. You should take a look at its path.

Comment: @ThomasGros We don't have any repository hosted in our machine.

Comment: Did you try to install or use Rocksclusters ? If you did, you might have misconfigured something (I'm not familiar with it, I can't help you further with this). If you didn't you can disable this repository from `yum.conf`.

Comment: I disabled the repository and now I'm getting another repository error, I edit the question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the edited part :

You're using a depreciated version of CentOS. As seen in the readme found in [CentOS 5 repo](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5) :

> This directory (and version of CentOS) is depreciated.
>
> CentOS-5 is now past EOL
>
> You can get the last released version of centos 5.11 here:
>
> http://vault.centos.org/5.11/
>
> Please NOTE:  this is not being maintained for security since moving
>   to Vault. It will have security issues, you should upgrade to a new
>   version instead.

You can either upgrade you system to a more recent version of CentOS (recommended for security updates etc..), or change your current repos urls from `http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/` to `http://vault.centos.org/5.11/`